# Android: How to get values from date and time picker

Tags: java, android, date, time, datepicker

I am building a app in which i am trying to ask user to select the time, so i used `datePicker` and `timePicker` and a `button set`. So when he click on `set button` a `dialog box` comes and say like you have selected x date and x time or in any way a message should appear on screen like user have selected this time. So i built the code but as my app comes to that activity it always got forcefully stopped.There is no problem with the `xml file` relating to display the data because when i comment java lines of fetching the values from `datePicker` and `timePicker`, app works absolutely fine.
Still i am posting both files code for easy to understanding. also posting the log cat exception. I have removed all unnecessary code like import and packages and extra button etc To make it quick readable.

**This is the code of `.xml` file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="10"
android:id="@+id/commonlayout" android:background="#FFFFFF">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"> <!--header-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"          
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>            
        </RelativeLayout>           
</LinearLayout>
 <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
<DatePicker android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/datePicker"></DatePicker>
<TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
  android:layout_height="wrap_content</TimePicker>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnSetDateTime"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
     <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Next"                       
        android:id="@+id/btnNext1" />   
  </TableRow>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>    
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lldata"
    android:layout_weight="8" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#FFFFFF">           
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible" 
    android:layout_margin="0dp">     
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the code of `TimeDate.java`:**

```
public class TimeDate extends Activity
{


Button  btnNext;
private TextView dateText;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time_date);
        btnNext=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnNext1);           
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                    Intent myintent = new  Intent(TimeDate.this, Next.class);
                    startActivity(myintent);
                    finish();
                    }
        });
        ScrollView DTPicker = (ScrollView) View.inflate(TimeDate.this,R.layout.time_date, null);

        Button  btnSet = (Button) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.btnSetDateTime);
        final   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strDateTime = dp.getYear() + "-" + (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dp.getDayOfMonth() + " "+ tp.getCurrentHour() + ":" + tp.getCurrentMinute();}});

       AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(TimeDate.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Reminder");
        alert.setView(DTPicker);
        alert.show();

 }       
}
```

**This is the `logcat` exception:**

```
04-27 11:48:24.830: D/AndroidRuntime(812): Shutting down VM
04-27 11:48:24.830: W/dalvikvm(812): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-27 11:48:24.851: E/AndroidRuntime(812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 11:48:24.851: E/AndroidRuntime(812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ogtpl.android/com.ogtpl.android.TimeDate}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Comment: having same problem how to get these values.. please someone answer i'll surly vote for him/her :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't do anything extra, Your code is just prefect. Just remove the code of `ScrollLayout` or its attribute wherever you are using that. 
Lemme write the updated code for you from `ScrollLayout`

```
 final   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strDateTime = dp.getYear() + "-" + (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dp.getDayOfMonth() + " "+ tp.getCurrentHour() + ":" + tp.getCurrentMinute();

                Toast.makeText(TimeDate.this, "User selected " + strDateTime + "Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Generate a toast only if you want 
                finish();   // If you want to continue on that TimeDateActivity
                 // If you want to go to new activity that code you can also write here
            }});
```

Comment: GetCurrentHour was deprecated. Use getHour() now for 6.0+.

Answer (score 1):

```
ScrollView DTPicker = (ScrollView) View.inflate(TimeDate.this,R.layout.time_date, null);
Button  btnSet = (Button) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.btnSetDateTime);
final   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

replace the above line with below

```
ScrollView DTPicker = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
Button  btnSet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetDateTime);
final   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

Comment: sorry mate but still not working. this is the log cat exception W/dalvikvm(1007): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(1007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1007): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ogtpl.android/com.ogtpl.android.TimeDate}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: hey please try to help man i'll surly accpet and upvote your answer.

Comment: ok my mistake i am sorry but i have met few nerds before who are here only for reputation. SO sorry man but really i'll be thankful to you if you can sort out this problem

Comment: create a seprate xml file of scrollview and inflate it via inflater and then set it to alert dialog

Comment: that will surly work, i know because i have done that but i want to do this in one xml screen so is there any way to do it in one screen

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in this line:

```
ScrollView DTPicker = (ScrollView) View.inflate(TimeDate.this,R.layout.time_date, null);
```

You are inflating an XML containing `LinearLayout` as the root node, however you are type-casting it to `ScrollView` causing the `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

try following code....

**time_date.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="10" android:id="@+id/commonlayout"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llheader" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"> <!--header -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_header" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <DatePicker android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/datePicker" />
            <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button android:id="@+id/btnSetDateTime" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Set"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
                <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Next"
                    android:id="@+id/btnNext1" />
            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lldata" android:layout_weight="8" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="20dp" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_margin="0dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**DateTimeActivity.java**

```
public class DateTimeActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.time_date);
        setTitle("Reminder");

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext1);           
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myintent = new  Intent(DateTimeActivity.this, Next.class);
                startActivity(myintent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button  btnSet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetDateTime);
        final   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        final   TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strDateTime = dp.getYear() + "-" + (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dp.getDayOfMonth() + " "+ tp.getCurrentHour() + ":" + tp.getCurrentMinute();

                Toast.makeText(DateTimeActivity.this, "User has selected " + strDateTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                finish();// move to previous activity
            }});

    }       

}
```

Comment: Thanks man for help, but it is working like in a pop up. i want that this should be like the main screen. If you want i can give u a screenshot what i want